# Pattern matching in Big query vs SSMS-Return strings which contain special characters or numerics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a bit lost.

I've had a look at the documentation but I'm not sure if you can use LIKE and pattern match in Big Query the same as SSMS.

The code shown here works in SSMS but the results are not correct in Big Query, so was wondering if there was another way to do it.

```
WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '[a-Z]%'
```

I'm looking to return strings which contain special characters or numerics.

Answer (score 2):

Use [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) instead

```
where not regexp_contains(column_name, r'[a-zA-Z]')
```

Meantime, [LIKE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#:%7E:text=in%20the%20former.-,LIKE,-X%20%5BNOT%5D%20LIKE) is also supported as a comparison operator

Comment: Ok so a few questions. What is 'r' doing here? Even though 'LIKE' is supported can it be used in the same way or is it more appropiate to use REGEXP? Also i get an error that the character claSs range is invalid when i use [a-Z]. Thanks!

Comment: 1) The r means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored - you can search for more details [what r means in regexp](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=AOaemvLPBTyn5nwJlRiBT0x3SnzJevrMWQ:1634756564527&q=what+r+means+in+regexp) 2) LIKE does not support regex so you cannot match with regex 3) just copied whatever you had there w/o noticing that it is wrong - corrected `class range` - try now

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! Thats working now, and I can use this as a basis for other patterns :)